# How to get attr of jQuery html object passed with 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this, attr

JQuery/JS newbie here - but so far enjoying the learning experience.

My scenario:

I have multiple buttons like so:

```
<button id="thumb-1" class="thumbs">click 1</button>
<button id="thumb-2" class="thumbs">click 2</button>
<button id="thumb-3" class="thumbs">click 3</button>
```

When a user clicks one, I pass it to a custom function via the `this` keyword like so:

```
$('.thumbs').click(function(){
    $.fn.myFunc(this);
}
```

Which will send the jQuery object to the function, i.e the entire button html.

```
<button id="thumb-x" class="thumbs">click x</button>
```

Now what I want to do is grab the id of that button and store it on a string variable.
Using the following doesn't work of course a html button element has no attr method.

```
$.fn.myFunc = function(button) { 
    var id = button.attr('id');
}
```

Anybody have any simple ideas?

Thanks!
- James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use [**`attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) then convert button to jquery object or if you want to get id from `javascript` object then use `button.id`

```
$.fn.myFunc = function(button) { 

    var id = $(button).attr('id'); // with jquery object
    id = button.id; //with javascript object 
}
```

Comment: Yeah JS object property accessors is even better syntax wise :) cheers guys!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make it a jQuery object before using jQuery function

```
$.fn.myFunc = function(button) { 
    var id = $(button).attr('id');
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks soderslatt!

Answer (score 0):

if you send "this" from myFunc there is no need to use jquery attr we can access straightly which will be more faster and easier

```
$(".thumbs").click(function(){
$.fn.myFunc(this);
});
$.fn.myFunc = function(button) {
alert(button.id);
}
```

Refer the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/m2Ts5/18/

Thanks

Comment: Wow that's even better. I didn't realize it had those type of object properties applied to HTML objects. Thanks very much Sridhar!